# I develop cordova project with ionic 2 send base64 to server the image is corrupted

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, ionic2, base64

My purpose is to take a picture and send to server base64 with ajax call. My problem is when I send it to the server and test it on browser it's corrupted although it's display on the device fine and this problem only on ios android work fine and when I send the base64 I can open it in the browser my code for take a picture :

```
takePicture(qidSide) {
    Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        quality: 25,
        targetHeight: 700
    }).then((imageData) => {
        // imageData is a base64 encoded string
        if (qidSide == 'front') {

            this.QIDfront = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData);


        } else {
            this.QIDback = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
        }

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

and to send to server

```
var jsonBody = { frontQID: this.QIDfront.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity, backQid: this.QIDback.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity };
            this.xhrService.xhrCall({ method: 'post', url: 'updateSignature', data: jsonBody  }).then(data => {

                let response: any = data;

            }).catch(err => {


            });
```

Please can any one help as I'm on this issue from 3 days?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was i was sending the base64 as a plain string and this was wrong any url should encodeuri before sending it to the server the solution was :

```
var jsonBody = { frontQID: encodeURIComponent(this.QIDfront.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity), backQid: encodeURIComponent(this.QIDback.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity) };
```

and at the backend should decode it